# Programmable On/Off micro-controller to switch a lighting module on command

Tags: microcontroller, power-electronics

Having a lighting module that uses an 12V (3.8A) adaptor with an integrated manual switch, what are the available options on embedding a programmable micro controller so as to turn on/off the light using an arduino-like software?

As a programmer, rather than an electrical engineer, I assume that I could use the simplest  micro controller with a USB capability preferentially. Nevertheless, I am not quite sure over the available options that could potentially be adopted.

Any clues would be appreciated!

[image]

Comment: We don't really do "shopping recommendations" here. But you will definitely find everything you need on either SparkFUN or Adafruit. On sparkfun, for example search the word "relay" in their tutorials section.

Comment: Ok I understand. thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using a microcontroller with WiFi built-in. It is very likely that in the future atleast, you might need internet connectivity for your application. Try to use the lowest cost microcontroller with WiFi that supports the programming environment you prefer. Use the lowest priced one because for your switching purpose, you don't need much processing power.

It's a good idea to use a relay to switch the light. The microcontroller controls the relay. Think of adding functionality to detect when the power is off (say due to a power-cut) and report that to the end-user. Use a battery so your microcontroller works for enough time to report the power cut and possibly monitor the supply for a certain period of time.

Don't forget to refer to the voltage and current ranges in datasheets of all components so you don't burn any component.

Comment: Thank you .. very helpful answer!